# Clone GIT from SAMBA network share

Tags: networking, samba, git

Has anybody successfully cloned GIT repository to Ubuntu from a SAMBA network share?

I have access over file manager and can ls over command line, but cannot clone

Also, in `git cola`, `qgit` and `gitg` I cannot see mounted SAMBA network share.

Comment: what error are you getting trying to clone of the git repository, and what's the command you're running?

Answer (score 4):

Use this manual (section 'Connecting using CIFS') to mount remote repository:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

```
sudo mount -t cifs //IP_ADDRESS/git/repo.git ~/git/mnt/repo.git -o username=samba_user,noexec
```

Then,

```
git clone ~/git/mnt/repo.git/
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this would be to clone gvfs user-mounts

```
git clone /run/user/<username>/gvfs/path_to_repo/repo.git
```

This avoids mounting issues

See also: [Where can I find the mount point for SMB shares in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343205/where-can-i-find-the-mount-point-for-smb-shares-in-13-04)

Comment: With samba, I could do it by directly by accessing the samba project files from the local. Did not need to clone the repo.

Comment: Worked fine for me, but later I failed to push.