# Cannot play files over samba share on MATE 15.04

Tags: samba, vlc, 15.04, video-streaming

When I try to open video files from my home server I get the error:

> VLC is unable to open the MRL

I have never had this issue before. Opening internet RMTP streams works fine and firewall is disabled.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10):

A year later... I just discovered that VLC does not use whatever connection the desktop supplies, whether it's Gnome or KDE.
It creates its own using credentials defined in the settings:

Tools > Preferences

Show settings: All

Input / Codecs > Access Modules > SMB

Thanks to [Joris](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215010757/http://jorisvandijk.com/2013/vlc-wont-play-smb-shares/) for the information.

---

If it's missing install a plugin:

```
apt-get install vlc-plugin-samba
```

Comment: Thank you, a more meaningful error message might be something for them to consider...

Comment: FYI link is dead

Comment: @ElderGeek: I assume you fixed it, because it seems to work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

according to this: 
[Question on Network Drives | Ubuntu MATE Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/solved-question-on-network-drives/1210/3) 
you need to install the 'vlc-plugin-samba'. Because it is not installed by default. What a mess!
That did the trick here, but I also upgraded to vlc 3.0, because I thought this would help, but it didn't. Please let me know if it will work if you just install the plugin.

With kind regards
Mangnoppa

Comment: I can confirm now that just installing vlc-plugin-samba with `sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-samba` is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a password protected share, you'll have to mount it with cifs:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
mkdir /mnt/share_name
```

then add this line to your /etc/fstab :

```
//server_ip/share_name        /mnt/share_name    cifs    username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm      0       0
```

and run

```
mount -a
```

play it from `/mnt/share_name`

Answer (score 1):

Once you mounted the samba Share with [nemo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo), you can call vlc like this:

> vlc /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=YOURSERVER,share=YOURPATH

In this approach the authentification is transparently managed within gnome, which allows to save the password in your keychain.

Comment: wow, this is so much easier; I've tried the SMB plugin method, but after configuring it, I couldn't find how to actually open the share /shrug

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 15.04, 15.10 there is a confirmed bug in the gvfs package. This causes any mounts made no to show up in /run/user//gvfs.

[Where can I find the mount point for SMB shares in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343205)

VLC uses these mounts to access and play files.
If the mounts are not available, vlc uses the samba-plugin to create a connection.

A workaround is to kill the gvfsd, so a new deamon will be created when the files are accessed.

```
killall --user $(id -un) gvfsd
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting VLC in Ubuntu to play a windows share, nothing would be displayed if I navigated to the folder.  What worked for me was as above activating the smb pluginl and then using add multiple files, I was able to drag and drop my entire music share into VLC, and it played perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

i set in smb.conf

> min protocol = SMB1
>
> max protocol = SMB1

and works fine